# What causes replacement (�)(<?>) characters messages from "?" package in Android Studio's Logcat?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, logcat

I'm developing an app on Android Studio.
Since a couple of days, as soon as I connect my Xiaomi 8 for debugging purposes the log gets flooded with random character messages from a package named "?" even if it's set up as "Show only selected application".

The logged text is always a combination of replacement character and random prints like this:

```
�k�#r
�|.
```

The pattern changes when I reboot the phone and it usually comes right after system messages like this:

```
? D/SignalClusterView: updateMobileTypeImage  0

?pV����.
? D/NetworkController.MobileSignalController(1): 4G level = 2

?pV����.
? W/swapper/4: type=1400 audit(0.0:2480): avc: denied { kill } for capability=5 scontext=u:r:kernel:s0 tcontext=u:r:kernel:s0 tclass=capability permissive=0

?pV����.
? D/SignalClusterView: updateMobileTypeImage  0

?pV����.

?pV����.
.
```

What is causing this? How can I stop this behaviour? Is everything broken? Thank you in advance!